# How to move view if only a certain textView is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uikeyboard

Hi I am using this code to move my view when a textView is selected, this is to make sure my texView is visible for when the keyboard pops up.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)   
}


func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height

}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!

    let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    let offset: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size

    if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            })
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
        })
    }
    print(self.view.frame.origin.y)

}


override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)

}
```

[image]

How can i only move the view if the bottom textView is selected? Because currently if you select the uppermost textView it moves half of it off screen.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: If your `UITextView`s will not themselves have vertical scroll, why don't you embed them both (and any other content) in a single scrollview that allows the whole screen to be scrolled? That way you can scroll the scroll view instead of adjusting individual view's frames. As for differentiating the `UITextField`s apart, use the delegate methods, as @konrad.bajtyngier suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the notification callbacks check for `bottomTextView.isFirstResponder()` and move the view only if its true. Otherwise don't move the view.

Answer (score 1):

Make your class a `UITextViewDelegate` like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` set only the bottom textView to be controlled by the delegate:

```
bottomTextView.delegate = self
```

Then you can use these functions, changing the values to suit your needs:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
}


func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 150
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than only moving the keyboard for a single text field, I suggest a more flexible approach.

What I do is to keep track of which text field is being selected and do some calculations to move the view controller's content view up just enough to expose the text field that is becoming active.

To do that you need to set up your view controller to be the text fields' delegates.

I have a development blog post that explains this in detail:

[Shifting views to make room for the keyboard](http://wareto.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/shifting-views-for-the-keyboard.html)

The code in that post is in Objective-C, but the concepts are identical. I'm not sure I have the same code in Swift that I can share (The only code I've found is in a project I did for a client.)

That blog post references a project called [RandomBlobs](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs.git) on Github.

Comment: say @duncanC.  You know how UITableView will do this for you.  In fact, as of ios10, is there anything else in ios that does this for you?  (perhaps a stack view or??)  I find it hard to find the doco on this, and I work with OS every day!  cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `delegate`. For example, you can set you bottom `textView`'s `delegate` to `self` (add `UITextViewDelegate` first of course) and implement the 
`textViewDidBeginEditing(_:)` method. When that's triggered, you will know that the user started editing this particular view.